# How to copy and paste an image from grid cell to grid cell in a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: pyqt, qgraphicsview

I have a custom QTableView class and a custom QGraphicsView class. I first copy a row that include an image from the table and paste it onto a cell in the grid (this part works). Then I want to copy an image from a grid cell to another grid cell (this part doesn't work).

Here's my code (without the calling code):

1. table:

   ```py
   from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, QPoint, QAbstractItemModel, QDataStream, QByteArray, QBuffer, QIODevice, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex, QByteArray
   from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QMenu
   from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QDrag, QImage


   import base64
   import json
   import sqlite3

   class CustomTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
       def __init__(self, db_path):
           super().__init__()
           self.db_path = db_path

           print("db_path: ", db_path)

           self.data_list = self.load_data()

       def load_data(self):
           with sqlite3.connect(self.db_path) as conn:
               cur = conn.cursor()
               cur.execute('SELECT PlantVar_id, Variete_Nom, Photo FROM tVarietes ORDER BY Variete_Nom')
               rows = cur.fetchall()

           return rows

       def getRowData(self, index):
           row = index.row()
           row_data = [self.data(self.index(row, col)) for col in range(self.columnCount())]
           return row_data


       def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
           return len(self.data_list)

       def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
           return 3

       def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
           if not index.isValid():
               return None

           row = index.row()
           column = index.column()

           if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
               if column == 2:
                   return None
               return self.data_list[row][column]

           if role == Qt.DecorationRole and column == 2:
               pixmap = QPixmap()
               pixmap.loadFromData(self.data_list[row][2])
               return pixmap.scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)

           if role == Qt.UserRole and column == 2:
               return self.data_list[row][column]

           return None


       def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
           headers = ['ID', 'Nom varieté', 'Photo']

           if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
               return headers[section]

           return None

       def dropMimeData(self, mime_data, action, row, column, parent):
           return False  # Prevent the source row from being removed

   class CustomDragTableView(QTableView):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           super().__init__(parent)

           #self.clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()

           self.setDragEnabled(True)
           self.setAcceptDrops(False)
           self.viewport().setAcceptDrops(False)
           self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
           #self.customContextualMenu = QMenu(self)
           # self.customContextualMenu.addAction("Copy")
           self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.contextMenuEvent)

       # #create method contextMenuEvent in the class CustomDragTableView

       def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
           context_menu = QMenu(self)
           copy_action = context_menu.addAction("Copy")
           action = context_menu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(event))

           # Hide the context menu immediately after the action is triggered
           context_menu.hide()

           if action == copy_action:
               self.copy_selection()

       def copy_selection(self):
           selected_rows = sorted(set(index.row() for index in self.selectedIndexes()))
           if not selected_rows:
               return

           clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
           mime_data = QMimeData()

           # Just handling the first selected row for simplicity
           row = selected_rows[0]
           plant_var_id = self.model().data(self.model().index(row, 0))
           image_data = None
           pixmap = self.model().data(self.model().index(row, 2), Qt.DecorationRole)

           if pixmap is not None:
               byte_array = QByteArray()
               buffer = QBuffer(byte_array)
               buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
               pixmap.save(buffer, "PNG")
               image_data = byte_array.toBase64().data().decode()

           mime_data.setText(f"{plant_var_id}|{image_data}")
           clipboard.setMimeData(mime_data)


       def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
           if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
               index = self.currentIndex()
               if index.isValid() and index.column() == 2:

                   # Get row data using the custom getRowData() method
                   row_data = self.model().getRowData(index)

                   # Encode the image if present in the row data
                   row_data_dict = {idx: (self.encode_image(value) if isinstance(value, QImage) else (str(value) if value is not Ellipsis else "NON_SERIALIZABLE")) for idx, value in enumerate(row_data)}

                   row_data_json = json.dumps(row_data_dict)

                   # Create the MIME data
                   mime_data = QMimeData()
                   mime_data.setData("application/x-rowdata-json", row_data_json.encode("utf-8"))

                   drag = QDrag(self)
                   drag.setMimeData(mime_data)

                   #drag.exec(supportedActions)
                   action = drag.exec(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)

       @staticmethod
       def encode_image(image):
           byte_array = QByteArray()
           buffer = QBuffer(byte_array)
           buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
           image.save(buffer, "PNG")
           return base64.b64encode(byte_array).decode("utf-8")
   ```
2. grid:

   ```py
   from PySide6.QtCore import (QRectF, QPointF, QSize, Qt, QDataStream, QIODevice, QByteArray, Signal, QObject)
   from PySide6.QtGui import (QFont, QPainter, QPen, QBrush, QColor, QTransform, QImage, QPixmap, QIcon, QDrag, QDragEnterEvent, QDropEvent, QCursor, QMouseEvent, QKeySequence, QContextMenuEvent)
   from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QLabel, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsItem, QWidget, QStyle, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QMessageBox, QMenu)

   #import QFont from PySide6 import QtGui
   import base64
   import json

   #from FormNumpy_Test import FormEditGrid

   class GraphicsTextImageItem(QGraphicsItem):
       ''' '''

       def __init__(self, row_data, parent=None):
               super().__init__(parent)

               # Store the row data for this item
               self.row_data = row_data

               # Create a QGraphicsPixmapItem child to hold the image
               self.image_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(self)
               self.image_item.setPos(10, 10)

               # Create a QGraphicsTextItem child to hold the text
               self.text_item = QGraphicsTextItem(self)
               self.text_item.setPos(10, 60)

               # Update the item with the row data
               self.update_item()

       def update_item(self):
           # Set the pixmap on the image item
           plantvar_id, variete_nom, photo = self.row_data
           pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(photo)
           self.image_item.setPixmap(pixmap)

           # Set the text on the text item
           self.text_item.setPlainText(variete_nom)
           self.text_item.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.black)
           self.text_item.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10, QFont.Bold))

       def show_text(self, row_data):
           plantvar_id, variete_nom, photo = row_data
           self.text_item.setPlainText(variete_nom)
           self.text_item.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.red)
           self.text_item.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10, QFont.Bold))

       def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
           ''' Handles the mouse release event '''
           if self._moving_item:
               # Calculate the cell position where the drop occurred
               item_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
               cell_size = self.cell_size
               x = int(item_pos.x() // cell_size) * cell_size
               y = int(item_pos.y() // cell_size) * cell_size

               # Check if the cell already contains an item, and remove it if so
               cell_items = self.scene.items(QRectF(x, y, cell_size, cell_size))
               for cell_item in cell_items:
                   if isinstance(cell_item, QGraphicsItem):
                       self._moving_item = cell_item.parentItem()
                       self.scene.removeItem(cell_item)
                       break

               # Reposition the item to the cell position
               self._moving_item.setPos(x, y)
               self._moving_item = None
           else:
               # Clear the cell if it contains an item
               item_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
               cell_size = self.cell_size
               cell_rect = QRectF(item_pos.x(), item_pos.y(), cell_size, cell_size)
               cell_items = self.scene.items(cell_rect)
               for cell_item in cell_items:
                   if isinstance(cell_item, QGraphicsItem):
                       self.scene.removeItem(cell_item)

           QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)

       def dropEvent(self, event):
           if event.mimeData().hasImage():
               # Get the dropped image from the mime data
               image = QImage(event.mimeData().imageData())

               # Resize the dropped image to fit the item
               pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image).scaled(self.image_item.boundingRect().size().toSize())

               # Set the pixmap on the image item
               self.image_item.setPixmap(pixmap)

               event.accept()
           else:
               event.ignore()

   class MyCustomGrid(QGraphicsView):
       dropSignal = Signal(int, int, QPixmap)
       customContextMenuRequested = Signal(QContextMenuEvent)

       def __init__(self, parent=None, data=None):
           super(MyCustomGrid, self).__init__(parent)

           self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
           self.data = data
           self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
           self.setRenderHint(QPainter.TextAntialiasing)

           self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
           self.setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing, True)
           self.setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView.DontSavePainterState, True)
           self.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.FullViewportUpdate)
           self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
           self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

           self.cell_size = 35
           self.grid_width = 20
           self.grid_height = 20

           self.context_menu_position = None

           self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
           self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu_event)


           # Create cells and add them to the scene
           for i in range(self.grid_width):
               for j in range(self.grid_height):
                   cell_item = QGraphicsRectItem(i * self.cell_size, j * self.cell_size, self.cell_size, self.cell_size)
                   cell_item.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
                   cell_item.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
                   cell_item.setData(0, (i, j))
                   self.scene().addItem(cell_item)

       def drawForeground(self, painter, rect):    # OK
           ''' OK '''
           grid_color = QColor('gray')
           grid_color.setAlpha(25)
           grid_pen = QPen(grid_color)
           grid_pen.setWidth(0)
           painter.setPen(grid_pen)

           left = int(rect.left()) - (int(rect.left()) % self.cell_size)
           top = int(rect.top()) - (int(rect.top()) % self.cell_size)

           # Draw vertical lines
           x = left
           while x < rect.right():
               painter.drawLine(x, rect.top(), x, rect.bottom())
               x += self.cell_size

           # Draw horizontal lines
           y = top
           while y < rect.bottom():
               painter.drawLine(rect.left(), y, rect.right(), y)
               y += self.cell_size

       def mousePressEvent(self, event):
           if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
               self.context_menu_event(event)
           else:
               super(MyCustomGrid, self).mousePressEvent(event)

       def context_menu_event(self, event):

           # self.signals.context_menu_requested.emit(event)
           # self.customContextMenuRequested.emit(event)

           context_menu = QMenu(self)
           copy_action = context_menu.addAction("Copy")
           cut_action = context_menu.addAction("Cut")
           paste_action = context_menu.addAction("Paste")
           remove_action = context_menu.addAction("Remove")

           self.context_menu_position = event.pos()  # Store the global position of the right-clicked position
           action = context_menu.exec(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.context_menu_position))

           if action == copy_action:
               self.copy_selection(event)
           elif action == cut_action:
               self.copy_selection()
               self.remove_item()
           elif action == paste_action:
               self.paste_data()
           elif action == remove_action:
               self.remove_item()


       def paste_data(self, plant_var_id=None, image_data=None):
           if plant_var_id is None or image_data is None:
               clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
               mime_data = clipboard.mimeData()
               if mime_data.hasText():
                   text_data = mime_data.text().split('|')
                   plant_var_id = text_data[0]
                   image_data = text_data[1] if len(text_data) > 1 else None

           pixmap = QPixmap()
           if image_data and image_data != "None":
               pixmap.loadFromData(QByteArray.fromBase64(image_data.encode()))
           else:
               pixmap = None

           if self.context_menu_position:
               scene_pos = self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position)
               cell_x = int(scene_pos.x() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
               cell_y = int(scene_pos.y() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
               cell_pos = QPointF(cell_x, cell_y)

               cell_item = self.cell_item_at(cell_pos)
               if cell_item:
                   # Remove any existing pixmap from the cell item
                   for item in cell_item.childItems():
                       if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                           self.scene().removeItem(item)

                   if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
                       # Scale the pixmap based on cell_size
                       scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(
                           cell_item.rect().size().toSize(),
                           Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                           Qt.SmoothTransformation
                       )
                       pixmap_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(scaled_pixmap)
                       pixmap_item.setPos(cell_item.pos() + cell_item.rect().topLeft())
                       pixmap_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
                       pixmap_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
                       pixmap_item.setZValue(1)
                       self.scene().addItem(pixmap_item)

       def copy_selection(self):
           self.serialize(self)

       def serialize(self) -> QByteArray:
           """
           Serialize the object into a byte array using QDataStream.
           Returns: QByteArray: Serialized data.
           """
           data = QByteArray()
           stream = QDataStream(data, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
           stream.writeInt(type(self).__name__)
           self.write(stream)
           return data

       def write(self, stream):
           pass

       def deserialize(self, data: QByteArray):
           """
           Deserialize the object from a byte array using QDataStream.
           Args: data (QByteArray): Serialized data.
           """
           stream = QDataStream(data, QIODevice.ReadOnly)
           self.read(stream)

       def read(self, stream):
           pass

       def remove_item(self):
           items = self.items(self.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos()))
           for item in items:
               if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                   self.scene().removeItem(item)
                   break

       def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
           if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"):
               event.accept()
           else:
               event.ignore()

       def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
           if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"):
               event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
               event.accept()
           else:
               event.ignore()

       def dropEvent(self, event):
           if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"):
               bytearray = event.mimeData().data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist")
               data_stream = QDataStream(bytearray, QIODevice.ReadOnly)
               row = -1
               col = -1
               row_data = {}

               while not data_stream.atEnd():
                   row, col, map_items = {}, {}, {}
                   data_stream >> row >> col >> map_items

                   if row != -1 and col != -1:
                       for k, v in map_items.items():
                           if k == 0:  # PlantVar_id column
                               plant_var_id = v
                           elif k == 2:  # Photo column
                               image_data = v

               self.row_copied.emit(plant_var_id, image_data)

           super().dropEvent(event)

       def keyPressEvent(self, event):
           if event.matches(QKeySequence.Copy):
               self.copy_selection()
           else:
               super().keyPressEvent(event)



       def create_and_add_item(self, plant_var_id, pixmap):
           if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
               # Scale the pixmap based on cell_size
               scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(
                   QSize(self.cell_size, self.cell_size), 
                   Qt.KeepAspectRatio, 
                   Qt.SmoothTransformation
               )
               item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(scaled_pixmap)
               item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
               if self.context_menu_position:
                   scene_pos = self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position)
                   item.setPos(
                       scene_pos.x() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size,
                       scene_pos.y() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size
                   )
               else:
                   item.setPos(self.mapToScene(0, 0))
               self.scene().addItem(item)
               self.dropSignal.emit(plant_var_id, item.pos().x(), item.pos().y())

       def resizeEvent(self, event):

           #print("resizeEvent called")

           super().resizeEvent(event)
           self.fitInView(self.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

       def cell_item_at(self, pos):    # OK
           ''' OK '''
           items = self.scene().items(pos)
           for item in items:
               if isinstance(item, QGraphicsRectItem):
                   return item
           return None
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solutions for my own question. I can now copy, cut, paste and delete images in the grid.

Here's the updated `MyCustomGrid` class:

```py
class MyCustomGrid(QGraphicsView):
    dropSignal = Signal(int, int, QPixmap)
    customContextMenuRequested = Signal(QContextMenuEvent)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, data=None):
        super(MyCustomGrid, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.data = data
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.TextAntialiasing)

        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing, True)
        self.setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView.DontSavePainterState, True)
        self.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.FullViewportUpdate)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.cell_size = 35
        self.grid_width = 20
        self.grid_height = 20

        self.context_menu_position = None

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu_event)

        self.element_cut = 0    #on met le compteur de cut à 0

        # Create cells and add them to the scene
        for i in range(self.grid_width):
            for j in range(self.grid_height):
                cell_item = QGraphicsRectItem(i * self.cell_size, j * self.cell_size, self.cell_size, self.cell_size)
                cell_item.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
                cell_item.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
                cell_item.setData(0, (i, j))
                self.scene().addItem(cell_item)

    def drawForeground(self, painter, rect):    # OK
        ''' OK '''
        grid_color = QColor('gray')
        grid_color.setAlpha(25)
        grid_pen = QPen(grid_color)
        grid_pen.setWidth(0)
        painter.setPen(grid_pen)

        left = int(rect.left()) - (int(rect.left()) % self.cell_size)
        top = int(rect.top()) - (int(rect.top()) % self.cell_size)

        # Draw vertical lines
        x = left
        while x < rect.right():
            painter.drawLine(x, rect.top(), x, rect.bottom())
            x += self.cell_size

        # Draw horizontal lines
        y = top
        while y < rect.bottom():
            painter.drawLine(rect.left(), y, rect.right(), y)
            y += self.cell_size

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.context_menu_event(event)
        else:
            super(MyCustomGrid, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def context_menu_event(self, event):
        ''' Handles the context menu event '''
        context_menu = QMenu(self)
        copy_action = context_menu.addAction("Copy")
        cut_action = context_menu.addAction("Cut")
        paste_action = context_menu.addAction("Paste")
        remove_action = context_menu.addAction("Remove")

        self.context_menu_position = event.pos()  # Store the global position of the right-clicked position
        action = context_menu.exec(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.context_menu_position))

        if action == copy_action:
            self.copy_selection()
        elif action == cut_action:
            self.copy_selection()
            self.element_cut = 1   # pour identifier l'existence d'un élément cut
            self.remove_item()
        elif action == paste_action:
            self.paste_data()
        elif action == remove_action:
            self.remove_item()

    def copy_selection(self):
        ''' Copy the selected cell in the grid to the clipboard '''

        # Get the QGraphicsItem at the cursor position
        item = self.scene().itemAt(self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position), QTransform())

        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()

        if self.context_menu_position:
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position)
            cell_x = int(scene_pos.x() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
            cell_y = int(scene_pos.y() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
            cell_pos = QPointF(cell_x, cell_y)

            cell_item = self.cell_item_at(cell_pos)

            if cell_item:
                if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                    #Clear the clipboard
                    clipboard.clear()

                    #Retrieve the pixmap from the QGraphicsItem
                    myPixmap = item.pixmap()
                    #Copy the QPixmap to the clipboard
                    clipboard.setPixmap(myPixmap)        
                else:
                    QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "This Cell is empty. There's nothing to copy")
                    return


    def paste_data(self, plant_var_id=None, image_data=None):
        ''' Paste the data from the clipboard to the grid'''
        
        # Get the QGraphicsItem at the cursor position
        item = self.scene().itemAt(self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position), QTransform())

        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()

        if plant_var_id is None or image_data is None:
            
            mime_data = clipboard.mimeData()
            if mime_data.hasText():
                text_data = mime_data.text().split('|')
                plant_var_id = text_data[0]
                image_data = text_data[1] if len(text_data) > 1 else None
            elif mime_data.hasImage():
                image_data = self.convertPixmapToByteArray(clipboard.pixmap())
        
        pixmap = QPixmap()

        if image_data and image_data != "None":
            pixmap.loadFromData(QByteArray.fromBase64(image_data.encode()))
        else:
            pixmap = None
        
        if self.context_menu_position:
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position)
            cell_x = int(scene_pos.x() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
            cell_y = int(scene_pos.y() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
            cell_pos = QPointF(cell_x, cell_y)

            cell_item = self.cell_item_at(cell_pos)

            if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "This cell already has an image")
                return
            else:
                if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
                    # Scale the pixmap based on cell_size
                    scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(
                        cell_item.rect().size().toSize(),
                        Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                        Qt.SmoothTransformation
                    )
                    pixmap_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(scaled_pixmap)
                    pixmap_item.setPos(cell_item.pos() + cell_item.rect().topLeft())
                    pixmap_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
                    #pixmap_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
                    pixmap_item.setZValue(1)
                    #coller l'image dans la cellule
                    self.scene().addItem(pixmap_item)

                    if self.element_cut is not None and self.element_cut != 0:   # pour identifier l'existence d'un élément cut
                        clipboard.clear()   #sinon, la copie reste dans le clipboard et on peut encore la coller ailleurs
                        self.element_cut = 0    #on remet le compteur à 0



    def convertPixmapToByteArray(self, pixmap):
        ba = QByteArray()
        buffer = QBuffer(ba)
        buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        pixmap.save(buffer, "PNG", 75)
        #pixmap.setDevicePixelRatio(1.0) # set the resolution to 2x
        return ba.toBase64().data().decode()                

    def convertByteArrayToPixmap(self, ba):
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(QByteArray.fromBase64(ba.encode()))
        return pixmap

    def remove_item(self):
        ''' Delete the selected cell in the grid '''

        # Get the QGraphicsItem at the cursor position
        item = self.scene().itemAt(self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position), QTransform())

        if self.check_cell_hasImage(item):
            self.scene().removeItem(item)
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "This cell has no image to delete")
            return

    def check_cell_hasImage(self, item):
        ''' Vérifie si la cellule item contient une image'''
        if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"):
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"):
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"):
            bytearray = event.mimeData().data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist")
            data_stream = QDataStream(bytearray, QIODevice.ReadOnly)
            row = -1
            col = -1
            row_data = {}

            while not data_stream.atEnd():
                row, col, map_items = {}, {}, {}
                data_stream >> row >> col >> map_items

                if row != -1 and col != -1:
                    for k, v in map_items.items():
                        if k == 0:  # PlantVar_id column
                            plant_var_id = v
                        elif k == 2:  # Photo column
                            image_data = v

            self.row_copied.emit(plant_var_id, image_data)

        super().dropEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.matches(QKeySequence.Copy):
            self.copy_selection()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def create_and_add_item(self, plant_var_id, pixmap):
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            # Scale the pixmap based on cell_size
            scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(
                QSize(self.cell_size, self.cell_size), 
                Qt.KeepAspectRatio, 
                Qt.SmoothTransformation
            )
            item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(scaled_pixmap)
            item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
            if self.context_menu_position:
                scene_pos = self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position)
                item.setPos(
                    scene_pos.x() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size,
                    scene_pos.y() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size
                )
            else:
                item.setPos(self.mapToScene(0, 0))
            self.scene().addItem(item)
            self.dropSignal.emit(plant_var_id, item.pos().x(), item.pos().y())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):

        #print("resizeEvent called")

        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.fitInView(self.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def cell_item_at(self, pos):    # OK
        ''' OK '''
        items = self.scene().items(pos)
        for item in items:
            if isinstance(item, QGraphicsRectItem):
                return item
        return None
```

I hope this code may be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned version of the grid's code. The previous version contained some legacy code from an attempt to implement drag & drop:

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QPointF, Qt, QBuffer, QIODevice, QByteArray)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QPainter, QPen, QColor, QTransform, QPixmap)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QMessageBox, QMenu)
   
class MyCustomGrid(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, data=None):
        super(MyCustomGrid, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.data = data
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.TextAntialiasing)

        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing, True)
        self.setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView.DontSavePainterState, True)
        self.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.FullViewportUpdate)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.cell_size = 35
        self.grid_width = 20
        self.grid_height = 20

        self.context_menu_position = None

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu_event)

        self.element_cut = 0    #on met le compteur de cut à 0

        # Create cells and add them to the scene
        for i in range(self.grid_width):
            for j in range(self.grid_height):
                cell_item = QGraphicsRectItem(i * self.cell_size, j * self.cell_size, self.cell_size, self.cell_size)
                cell_item.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
                cell_item.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
                cell_item.setData(0, (i, j))
                self.scene().addItem(cell_item)

    def drawForeground(self, painter, rect):
        ''' Draws the grid's foreground '''
        grid_color = QColor('gray')
        grid_color.setAlpha(25)
        grid_pen = QPen(grid_color)
        grid_pen.setWidth(0)
        painter.setPen(grid_pen)

        left = int(rect.left()) - (int(rect.left()) % self.cell_size)
        top = int(rect.top()) - (int(rect.top()) % self.cell_size)

        # Draw vertical lines
        x = left
        while x < rect.right():
            painter.drawLine(x, rect.top(), x, rect.bottom())
            x += self.cell_size

        # Draw horizontal lines
        y = top
        while y < rect.bottom():
            painter.drawLine(rect.left(), y, rect.right(), y)
            y += self.cell_size
    
    ########### context menu, copy, cut, paste, remove ###############
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.context_menu_event(event)
        else:
            super(MyCustomGrid, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def context_menu_event(self, event):
        ''' Handles the context menu event '''
        context_menu = QMenu(self)
        copy_action = context_menu.addAction("Copy")
        cut_action = context_menu.addAction("Cut")
        paste_action = context_menu.addAction("Paste")
        remove_action = context_menu.addAction("Remove")

        self.context_menu_position = event.pos()  # Store the global position of the right-clicked position
        action = context_menu.exec(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.context_menu_position))

        if action == copy_action:
            self.copy_selection()
        elif action == cut_action:
            self.copy_selection()
            self.element_cut = 1   # pour identifier l'existence d'un élément cut
            self.remove_item()
        elif action == paste_action:
            self.paste_data()
        elif action == remove_action:
            self.remove_item()

    def copy_selection(self):
        ''' Copy the image from the selected cell to the clipboard '''

        # Get the QGraphicsItem at the cursor position
        item = self.scene().itemAt(self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position), QTransform())

        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()

        if self.context_menu_position:
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position)
            cell_x = int(scene_pos.x() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
            cell_y = int(scene_pos.y() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
            cell_pos = QPointF(cell_x, cell_y)

            cell_item = self.cell_item_at(cell_pos)

            if cell_item:
                if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                    #Clear the clipboard
                    clipboard.clear()
                    #Retrieve the pixmap from the QGraphicsItem
                    myPixmap = item.pixmap()
                    #Copy the QPixmap to the clipboard
                    clipboard.setPixmap(myPixmap)        
                else:
                    QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "This Cell is empty. There's nothing to copy")
                    return

    def paste_data(self, plant_var_id=None, image_data=None):
        ''' Paste the data from the clipboard to the grid'''
        
        # Get the QGraphicsItem at the cursor position
        item = self.scene().itemAt(self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position), QTransform())

        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()

        if plant_var_id is None or image_data is None:
            
            mime_data = clipboard.mimeData()
            if mime_data.hasText():
                text_data = mime_data.text().split('|')
                plant_var_id = text_data[0]
                image_data = text_data[1] if len(text_data) > 1 else None
            elif mime_data.hasImage():
                image_data = self.convertPixmapToByteArray(clipboard.pixmap())
        
        pixmap = QPixmap()

        if image_data and image_data != "None":
            pixmap.loadFromData(QByteArray.fromBase64(image_data.encode()))
        else:
            pixmap = None
        
        if self.context_menu_position:
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position)
            cell_x = int(scene_pos.x() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
            cell_y = int(scene_pos.y() // self.cell_size * self.cell_size)
            cell_pos = QPointF(cell_x, cell_y)

            cell_item = self.cell_item_at(cell_pos)

            if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "This cell already has an image")
                return
            else:
                if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
                    # Scale the pixmap based on cell_size
                    scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(
                        cell_item.rect().size().toSize(),
                        Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                        Qt.SmoothTransformation
                    )
                    pixmap_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(scaled_pixmap)
                    pixmap_item.setPos(cell_item.pos() + cell_item.rect().topLeft())
                    pixmap_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
                    #pixmap_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
                    pixmap_item.setZValue(1)
                    #coller l'image dans la cellule
                    self.scene().addItem(pixmap_item)

                    if self.element_cut is not None and self.element_cut != 0:   # pour identifier l'existence d'un élément cut
                        clipboard.clear()   #sinon, la copie reste dans le clipboard et on peut encore la coller ailleurs
                        self.element_cut = 0    #on remet le compteur à 0

    def convertPixmapToByteArray(self, pixmap):
        ba = QByteArray()
        buffer = QBuffer(ba)
        buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        pixmap.save(buffer, "PNG", 75)

        return ba.toBase64().data().decode()                

    def remove_item(self):
        ''' Delete the selected cell in the grid '''

        # Get the QGraphicsItem at the cursor position
        item = self.scene().itemAt(self.mapToScene(self.context_menu_position), QTransform())

        if self.check_cell_hasImage(item):
            self.scene().removeItem(item)
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "This cell has no image to delete")
            return

    def check_cell_hasImage(self, item):
        ''' Vérifie si la cellule item contient une image'''
        if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def cell_item_at(self, pos):
        ''' Returns the item at position pos'''
        items = self.scene().items(pos)
        for item in items:
            if isinstance(item, QGraphicsRectItem):
                return item
        return None
```